# How to Solve $y'' - 2y'+y=t\sin(t)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How should I solve this differential equation? $$y''-2y'+y=t\sin(t)$$

I used symbolab calculator because it costs lots calculations, but there was a point I don't understand. They assume a solution of the form for $$y=a_0t\sin (t)+a_1t\cos(t)=a_2\sin(t)+a_3\cos(t)$$ Why is this assumed like this? Are there particular rules for this?

Comment: They're likely employing [the method of undetermined coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients) ("Example 1" on that page seems particularly relevant).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the homogeneous par $$y''(x)-2y'(x)+y(x)=0.$$  Put $y=e^{mx}$ get $m=1$ which is a double root so its solutions are 
$y_1(x)=e^{x}$, $y_2(x)=xe^x$ and the general solution is $$y(x)=A e^x +B xe^x.$$
Now the inhomogeneous ODE $$Y''(x)-2Y'(x)+Y(x)=x\sin x=f(x)$$ is best solved bt the Method of Variation of Parameters, where $$Y(x)=C_1(x) y_1(x)+ C_2(x) y_2(x)~~~(1)$$ and 
$$C_1(x)=-\int \frac{f(x) y_2(x)}{W(x)} dx+A, ~~~C_2(x)=\int \frac{f(x) y_1(x)}{W(x)} dx+B~~~~(2)$$ Where W is Wronskian of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ which is $W=[y_1 y'_2-y_2 y'_1].$ 
By inseting $y_1,y_2, f(x)$ from above, we get
$$C_1(x)=\frac{1}{2} e^{-x}(1+x)[(1+x) \cos x-(1-x) \sin x]+A,$$
$$C_2(x)=-\frac{1}{2} e^{-x} [(1+x) \cos x+x \sin x)]+B.$$ Inserting $y_1,y_2$ in (1) we get the complete solution

Answer (score 2):

$$y'' - 2y'+y=t\sin t\implies (D^2-2D+1)y=t\sin t\qquad \text{where}~~~~~ D\equiv\frac{d}{dt}$$

Roots of the trial equation are $~1,~1$

So complementary function (C.F.) is $$(a+b~t)~e^t$$where $~a,~b~$ are constants.

Particular integral (P.I.) is

$$P.I.~~=\frac{1}{D^2-2D+1}  (t\sin t)$$

$$= ~\text{Imaginary part of} ~\frac{1}{(D-1)^2} t~e^{it}$$

$$= ~\text{Imaginary part of} ~e^{it}\frac{1}{[(D+i) - 1]^2} t$$

$$= ~\text{Imaginary part of} ~\frac{e^{it}}{(i-1)^2}\left(1 + \frac{D}{i-1}\right)^{-2} t$$

$$= ~\text{Imaginary part of} ~-\frac{e^{it}}{2i}\left(1- \frac{2D}{i-1}+\cdots \right) t$$

$$= ~\text{Imaginary part of} ~-\frac{e^{it}}{2i} \left(t- \frac{2}{i-1}\right) $$

$$= ~\text{Imaginary part of} ~i\frac{e^{it}}{2}\left(t- \frac{2(i+1)}{-2}\right)$$

$$= ~\text{Imaginary part of} ~\frac{i}{2} (\cos t +i \sin t)\{(t+1)+i\}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2} \{(t+1)\cos t -\sin t\}$$

So the general solution is $$y(x)=C.F. +P.I.$$

$$=(a+b~t)~e^t+\frac{1}{2} \{(t+1)\cos t -\sin t\}$$where $~a,~b~$ are constants.

> For the Particular Integral (i.e., P.I.) there are some general rules
>
> $1.$ $\frac{1}{D + a} \phi (x) = e^{-ax}\int e^{ax}\phi(x)$
>
> $2.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} e^{ax} \phi(x) = e^{ax}\frac{1}{f(D+a)} \phi(x)$
>
> $3.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} x^{n} \sin ax  = $Imaginary part of $e^{iax}\frac{1}{f(D+ia)} x^n$
>
> $4.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} x^{n} \cos ax  = $Real part of $e^{iax}\frac{1}{f(D+ia)} x^n$
>
> $5.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} x^{n} (\cos ax + i\sin ax)  = \frac{1}{f(D)} x^n e^{iax}=e^{iax}\frac{1}{f(D+ia)} x^n$